# How to setup an if condition in the event no result is returned?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Good day,

I have the following query:

```
// Add email later on
let sqlSelectBoxInformation = "SELECT DISTINCT longestDimension, box_id from box WHERE occupied ='unoccupied'";

 connectionBoxInformation.query(sqlSelectBoxInformation, function(err, rows, fields) {

if (!err) {
  // Check to see if the user entered hashtag is found in the database
  // Create a variable to track if the item was found


        var data = {
         rows: rows,
         userHashtag: databaseHashtag
        }
        res.render('delivery/chooseBox', data);

       // Change the variable to true
       wasFound = true;

}
```

In the event that no results is returned because no result could satisfy those requirements, I would like to have an else statement that would render the user to another page, but I am not too sure how I would proceed.

Comment: Please don't tag-spam. This has nothing to do with the PHP [tag:mysqli] library, or [tag:npm].

Comment: What have you found in your research (in particular, your reading of the `query` function documentation)? Surely it says what the arguments you receive will be in various situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What module is that? I'm going to assume this is what you need.

```
if(!err){
    if(rows.length > 0){
    }
}
```